# How do you bring the schema name into an VIEW in Oracle?

Tags: oracle, view, database-schema

I am trying to create MVIEWs in a database with 50 identical schemas.  So the basic VIEW is pretty simple, but I need to add a column to the view that stores the source record's schema.  The tables in all 50 schemas start their unique keys from 0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Anyhow you must replace the view's ddl.

You may do it in this way:

```
create or replace view_name
as
select col1, col2, 'schema1' as schema_name
from schema1.table
union all
select col1, col2, 'schema2'
from schema2.table
union all
select col1, col2, 'schema3' 
from schema3.table
...
```

Comment: Thanks! I can't beleive I forgot just declaring it like that.  I was thinking it was way more complex when my DBA couldn't figure it out.